# Testing activities with category CATEGORY_INFO

Tags: android, android-intent

My Android app has this intent filter in its manifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO" />
    </intent-filter>
```

I'm using [CATEGORY_INFO](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_INFO) because I don't want this app showing in the applications list, but I do want to show app information upon installation via Google Play.

How do I test it to see whether it displays properly? (Appart from changing temporarily the category to `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` and running it from the applications list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it this way:

1. Create a new app entry in Google Play console
2. Upload the APK to this app entry in Beta Testing
3. Create a Google+ group to invite yourself to beta test the app (using an email address different than the one you use as a registered Android dev)
4. Using the link available only to beta testers, accept the invitation and download the app from Google Play
5. When clicking "Open" in the app's Play page, the CATEGORY_INFO activity will show

I know this may be overkill to test an apparently trivial feature, but in my case I needed to test the app with the CATEGORY_INFO activity interacting with a previously installed app in the device.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to test CATEGORY_INFO activities is with the activity manager and adb. Simply run this command: `adb shell am start -n com.example/.MainActivity`

For more info see [this](https://chris.orr.me.uk/android-apps-info-category/).